# Custom Wordpress plugin - PHP variables in shortcode not being displayed on pages

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Am building a Wordpress plugin and struggling with a weird issue. Probably a simple fix that I'm missing.

Have the following shortcode hook in my plugin.

```
add_shortcode( "example", "ah_create_shortcode" );
function ah_create_shortcode() {
    $return_string = '';

    $return_string .= '<section class="ah-lots">';
    $return_string .= '<div>' . $address . '</div>';
    $return_string .= '<div>Test Line</div>';
    $return_string .= '</section>';

    return $return_string;
}
```

When I place the shortcode on a page, i.e [example] - it outputs everthing apart from the $address variable. So I can see 'Test Line' on the actual page etc.

The $address variable exists as I can output it directly on the Plugin's admin page and it has a value.

I'm sure it's a simple fix, I'm relatively new to Wordpress. I've tried passing $address as an arg to the shortcode function, ensuring the variable is declared and has a value before the shortcode is created etc.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be defined elsewhere, in an "outside" context - but there definitively exists no variable `$address` within the variable scope of this function. _"I've tried passing $address as an arg to the shortcode function"_ - give proper details on what exactly you did there, please.

Comment: @CBroe I literally just added the $address variable as an arguement when declaring the function right after the shortcode hook. 

Thinking about it now, why am I surprised that didn't work when it's obvious I didn't actually pass it, I just declared the function and gave it an argument haha. Brain not working. 

Is there any way to pass arguements properly to these shortcode hooks? Would that solve this issue? The WP docs don't show it as possible.

Comment: Never mind, solved it. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

I was being incredibly stupid here. @CBroe knocked me in the right direction.

I updated the shortcode function to create the $address variable within it, instead of just above it.

Below code works fine.

```
add_shortcode( "example", "ah_create_shortcode" );
function ah_create_shortcode($address) {

    $lots = get_option('ah_lots');
    $returned_lots = json_decode($lots, true);

    if ($returned_lots) {
        $address =              $returned_lots['data']['data'][0]['address'];
        $short_description =    $returned_lots['data']['data'][0]['short_description'];
        $bedrooms =             $returned_lots['data']['data'][0]['bed_rooms'];
        $bathrooms =            $returned_lots['data']['data'][0]['bath_rooms'];
        $livingrooms =          $returned_lots['data']['data'][0]['living_rooms'];
        $image_url =            $returned_lots['data']['data'][0]['primary_image']['full_url'];

        // echo $address;
    } else {
        echo "Failed to retrieve address from JSON.";
    }

    $return_string = '';

    $return_string .= '<section class="ah-lots">';
    $return_string .= '<div>' . $address . '</div>';
    $return_string .= '<div>Test Line</div>';
    $return_string .= '</section>';

    return $return_string;
}
```